# How Can I display Images for a page like Vagabond do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a page:

http://demo.infotyke.com/uffshop/home/

Now I want to display images in background for MEN and WOMEN just like http://vagabond.com/

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

your image is not loaded correctly.
check the path

Comment: Sorry mate.
Still the same issue.
Browser couldnot render your image.
Please correct the path.

Comment: You are awesome! Its done! You were right :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the css `background-image` property,

as described at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: but he want's to diffrent backgrounds and i'm quite sure thats impossible to make only with css... Isn't it?

Comment: I think, its done but still images are not loading. please help.